# Is there a known performance regression with querying/eager loading/instantiating AR objects in Rails 4.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4.2

We're recently upgraded our stack from Rails 3.22.5 to Rails 4.2.8. We have both a big CRUD application in Rails, and a Sinatra API app. They both are on the same Ruby versions (2.4.1), the same ActiveRecord and ActiveSupport versions, and share the same database (Postgresql) and all of the model files.

We've also upgraded the Ruby versions, but switching back to the old Ruby version did not change anything, so I'll keep talking about the setup as-is.

It looks like, since the upgrade, our API responses have become 40%-50% slower in the worst cases (the Rails app responses have also slowed, but not as much). This example looks at the worst case, where we query for 100-200 "Message" records which contain a quite deep eager loaded hierarchy of associated models, using also ActsAsList and STI relations. Here is how they're queried:

```
  messages = property.
             messages.
             visible(property, opts[:days]).
             includes(:translations).
             includes(:gallery_images).
             includes(:place).
             includes(:property => :places).
             includes(:address => [:translations, template: :translations]).
             includes(:tags).
             includes(:interests => :interest_disablings).
             includes(:template => [
               :translations, {:interests => :interest_disablings}, :gallery_images, :property, :tags, {:address => [:translations, template: :translations]},
               {:template => [:translations, {:interests => :interest_disablings}, :gallery_images, :property, :tags, {:address => :translations}]}
             ]).
             includes({current_availability: [:property, :timing, :capacity, { custom_booking_fields: :translations }]}).
             includes(:availabilities).all.to_a
```

(The two nested :template references go to the same "messages" table, messages have two levels of "parent" templates. The "translations" come in via the Globalize gem)

Both this part (after which no more SQL calls are being made) and later processing (Hash/Array and Time/Timezone manipulation to build up an API response to be serialized to JSON) have slowed down.

When looking at RubyProf profiles before and after, I can see no obvious bottlenecks, except that it seems like there is more Arel/Association code happening now, but can't he sure of it.

I can also see similar slowdown by simply benchmarking this:

```
rails3:
>> Benchmark.measure { 1000.times {  Message.find(187812) } }.total
=> 0.29000000000000026
rails4:
>> Benchmark.measure { 1000.times {  Message.find(187812) } }.total
=> 0.5200000000000005
```

I can provide the profilings and any benchmarks, if needed.

Is this something that is known, i.e. were there tradeoffs being made in Rails and I'm now hitting a too-many-records case?

Update: I created blank Ruby on Rails apps each for the old (Ruby 2.3.1/Rails 3.2.22.5) and the new setup (Ruby 2.4.1/Rails 4.2.8), and copied the database.yml over to it so the blank apps use the same DB. Using also bare-bones model files (the originals have a lot of code), I still see a difference:

```
2.3.1 :009 > ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil; Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { Message.find(133147) } }.total
 => 0.29000000000000004
2.4.1 :009 > ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil; Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { Message.find(133147) } }.total
 => 0.41000000000000014
```

Comment: I think you should raise this issue on the rails github page.

Comment: Will do, good call :)

Comment: Oh well they can't help: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29114

Comment: Ok, I see, worth a shot though :)